# Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. while tring to debug jar

Tags: eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug the jar file with Remote JAVA Application debug.
I am getting 'Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.' error
following is stack trace..

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService$2.run(SocketTransportService.java:136)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you remember to enable debugging on the JVM you are trying to connect to? This is done through JAVA_OPTS when you run the remote JVM.

For example, to add debugging to tomcat, you would add these JAVA_OPTS when launching the java process:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Comment: Yes I am using following command
    java -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=55500 -jar myjar.jar
Also I'm using same port number in eclipse debug configuration and in command

Comment: It was able to find the bug,the host IP in debug configuration was different in my case it should be of my local machine...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're adding the debug flags BEFORE the reference to your Java program, otherwise they will be passed to the program itself rather than to Java.

Also, Eclipse can be weird sometimes and it doesn't automatically switch to the "Debug" perspective when you run the "Debug Configuration". After a successful debug session has been established, if you run it again thinking that it didn't run and/or silently failed, then you get the error message: "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused." So, always switch to the "Debug" perspective to see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you, the switch to debug view did the trick. This is so dumb! Such issues are the reason I detest eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is observing this behavior and have checked their Java command line arguments, port number and hostname, I was able to fix this issue by restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

For more recent versions of java the arguments should be:

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=XXXX

(suspend can be either y or n depending on whether you want the java process to wait until you attach the debugger before executing your program or not).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how universal this is but...
(Running openjdk 14+36 on a raspberry pi named 'tahoeServer')

You have to tell the JVM which interface to use.  If you just say

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=4445

then the JVM will listen on the 'localhost' interface and will NOT allow true remote debugging.  However, if you say

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=tahoeServer.local:4445

will allow connections from remote machines.

Again, I don't know if this is true on other versions of the JVM or other operating systems.